# When is a question considered spam and is deleted?

Tags: discussion

This question:

[Airpush for Android - What is fact and what a myth? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132301/airpush-for-android-what-is-fact-and-what-a-myth)

and some of the answers are in IMHO spam for airpush. The Q&A has no technical merit for a programmer.

Why was this question just closed, but not deleted? When is a question considered spam?

Comment: Discussing Airpush and its merrits, though off-topic, is different from having a vested interest in it and promoting it for commercial/financial gain.

Comment: I see what you mean, but bringing something off-topic up for discussion on SO can also be used as a form of promotion, in particular for a controversial business like Airpush which apparently doesn't care if the majority of devs don't like them as long as some do use them. To me the question, so off-topic, but so detailed, looks like an awareness-building attempt by someone with vested interest. No proof of this, but it just looks very promotional. Perhaps I'm being paranoid:)

Comment: A bit of proof would be nice though in the general case. Looking at this particular question I wouldn't care one bit if it got nuked, but I'm not convinced that it's outright spam.

Comment: After looking into the users here, I see no connection between them at all (in fact, they come from nearly opposite sides of the world). The user asking about this doesn't mention anything close to Airpush in their other posts. It looks to me like an honest question (if not a particularly on-topic or constructive one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% convinced it's spam, but it's odd that the same "Airpush" representative just happened to be around to answer these and *only* these questions.

The question itself doesn't seem to be spam, and the answerer does disclose his/her affiliation with the product; however, this doesn't mean that there isn't some sort of conspiracy to spam here.

However, the questions are clearly off-topic. I voted to delete the closed one and voted to close the others. Once they're closed, they can be voted to be deleted.

Comment: +1, though the Airpush only activity is not all that odd. I've seen representatives of various companies hunting only questions asked about their product, whether tagged as such or not. And those were usually clearly not spam.

Comment: Yeh, @Bart, I wouldn't flag it as spam just based on a gut feeling. I try to assume everyone is here with the best intentions in mind, but it would trigger me to investigate a bit further. :)